# swap multiple fields with single sql query

Tags: sql

I have a table salary, that looks like the one below, that has m=male and f=female values. I want to swap all f and m values with a single update query.

```
| id | name | sex | salary |
|----|------|-----|--------|
| 1  | A    | m   | 2500   |
| 2  | B    | f   | 1500   |
| 3  | C    | m   | 5500   |
| 4  | D    | f   | 500    |
```

After running the query, the above salary table should look like the following.

```
| id | name | sex | salary |
|----|------|-----|--------|
| 1  | A    | f   | 2500   |
| 2  | B    | m   | 1500   |
| 3  | C    | f   | 5500   |
| 4  | D    | m   | 500    |
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
UPDATE salary
SET sex = 'm'
WHERE sex = 'f' 
AND SET sex = 'f'
WHERE sex = 'm' ;
```

can anyone see where I am going wrong with my query?

Comment: you can use a `case` expression..your syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
UPDATE  @table
SET     [Sex] = CASE [Sex]
                  WHEN 'm' THEN 'f'
                  WHEN 'f' THEN 'm'
                END;
```